# Rails: Bad Associations? [has_many , through] How to test if working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, erd

I am  struggling with an issue in my data model. I do have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  has_many :claims #user-claims
  has_many :claims, through: :rulings, as: :commissars
...
end

class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users, through: :rulings, as: :commissars
 ...
end

class Ruling < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :claim
end
```

Error:

```
undefined method `commissars' for #<Claim:0xc5ac090>
```

Model Explanation:

User can write claims (A claim belongs to one user), and users could do the role of commissars to do the ruling of the claim (max numbers of commissars = 3 per claim).

Is there any way to fix this or improve the relationship?

Comment: Please show the `Ruling` model.

Comment: `class Ruling < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :claim
end`

Comment: @jvillian there you go, updated the first comment thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This domain model requires som pretty complex relations so there is no shame in not getting it on the first try.

Lets start with user and claims:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :claims, foreign_key: 'claimant_id',
                    inverse_of: :claimant
end

class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User',
                        inverse_of: :claims
end
```

This is a pretty basic one to many relation with a twist. Since User will have a bunch of relations to Claim we call the relation something other than the default `user` so that the nature of the relation is defined.

The `class_name: 'User'` option tells ActiveRecord to load the class User and use it to figure out what table to query and also what class to return the results as. Its needed whenever the class name cannot be directly derived from the name of the association. The option should be a string and not a constant due to the way Rails lazily resolves class dependencies.

Now lets add the commissar role. We will use `ruling` as the join table:

```
class Ruling < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :claim
  belongs_to :commissioner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Notice that here we have a relation to User that we call `commissioner` for clarity. Now we add the relations to `Claim`:

```
class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :claimant, class_name: 'User',
                        inverse_of: :claims
  has_many :rulings
  has_many :commissioners, through: :rulings
end
```

Then we need to setup the relations on the User side:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :claims, foreign_key: 'claimant_id',
                    inverse_of: :claimant

  # rulings as claimant
  has_many :rulings, through: :claims

  has_many :rulings_as_commissioner, class_name: 'Ruling',
                                     foreign_key: 'commissioner_id'
  has_many :claims_as_commissioner, through: :rulings_as_commissioner,
                                    source: :claim
end
```

Note the `source: :claim` option where we tell ActiveRecord which party we want from the join table.

Of course for this to work we need to setup the columns and the foreign keys properly. These migrations are to create the tables from scratch but you can easily rewrite them to alter your existing tables:

```
class CreateClaims < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :claims do |t|
      t.belongs_to :claimant, index: true, foreign_key: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    # we need to setup the fkey ourself since it is not conventional
    add_foreign_key :claims, :users, column: :claimant_id
  end
end

class CreateRulings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rulings do |t|
      t.belongs_to :claim, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :commissioner, index: true, foreign_key: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :rulings, :users, column: :commissioner_id
    add_index :rulings, [:claim_id, :commissioner_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

> max numbers of commissars = 3 per claim

This is not really part of the associations rather you would enforce this rule by adding a validation or an association callback.

```
class Ruling < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  validate :only_three_rulings_per_claim

  private 

    def only_three_rulings_per_claim
      if claim.rulings.size >= 3
        errors.add(:claim, "already has the max number of commissars")
      end
    end
end
```

See:

- [Rails Guides: Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns)
- [Rails Guides: the `has_many though:` relations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: We use `claim.rulings.size >= 3` and not `claim.rulings.size == 3` since it is entirely possible that more than 3 could sneak through due to race conditions!

Comment: Great solution, max. I don't know you, but I always learn a great deal by looking at your answers. Thank you for making SO a great place to hang out.

Comment: Also, extra kudos for including the migrations. That was a really nice add and super helpful (IMO).

Comment: thaaaaaank you  so much! I need to take it easy and understand everything you wrote down there. But it is outstanding how much effort you gave to it. :) +100 likes :P

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest you go back and read the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) carefully as I believe you have fundamentally misunderstood a number of things. The `as:` option, for instance, does not indicate role but, rather, the presence of a polymorphic join. Also, you can't declare `has_many :claims` twice on the same model. Anyway, go give it another read.

But, to your question - a functional although somewhat inelegant approach might look like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :claims 
  has_many :claim_commissars, foreign_key: "commissar_id"
  has_many :commissar_claims, through: :claim_commissars, class_name: "Claim" 
  #                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  #                                                     this bit may be wrong
  ...
end

class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  has_one    :ruling
  has_many   :claim_commissars
  has_many   :commissars, through: :claim_commissars
  ...
end

class ClaimCommissar < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :claim
  belongs_to :commissar, class_name: "User"
  ...
end

class Ruling < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :claim
  belongs_to :commissar, class_name: "User"
  ...
end
```

You would need to enforce your 'max 3 commissars` in the code.

This is not tested and you will likely need to fiddle with it to get it to go. But, hopefully, it sets you in a better direction.

Good luck!

Comment: Its a nice effort but the `ClaimCommissar` table is not needed since `Ruling`  already acts as a m2m join table between user and claim.

Comment: I agree with that. I guess I was thinking (not knowing anything about the domain) that it seemed odd to use `Ruling` as a join model because a ruling (this is my assumption - perhaps wrong) comes after a `Claim` has been associated with a `User` (as a writer) and with one or more `User`s as Commissar. Thus the introduction of the new model. But, that is all based on an assumption about the domain.

Comment: Also, I personally would have gone about this completely differently, using more proper roles and relationships - but that's because I have a library I've built that does this all seamlessly. Given the state of the OP models, I felt that a 'functional but somewhat inelegant' solution was appropriate. You solution, however, is excellent and in many regards our two solution are directionally aligned. I hope the OP finds these helpful.

Comment: Sure! I am still working on it to fully understand (new on rails) and first full project under my back so need time to process any way I really thank you for your big effort and of course it will solve the problem. :)